# Photoshop layer issues/making a specific layer larger

Tags: photoshop

i'm currently working on a project with photoshop.
Currently my image looks like this: http://prntscr.com/fpo3wq but when i add text to it which is longer than the layer is, then sadly it's out of "shape" e.g http://prntscr.com/fpo4ev
How would i fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

- Select the text tool.
- Click and drag to make a text box.
- Type what you want and adjust font size according to the layer size.
- Drag it around to fit it inside the layer.